# Push rejected on Heroku, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I know this problem occured here couple times but I tried solutions from no one seems to work. I'm having a problem pushing an app to Heroku. So I type `git push heroku master` and this error occurs:

```
remote:        An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.11), and Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
remote:  !
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to sleepy-atoll-4840.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/sleepy-atoll-4840.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/sleepy-atoll-4840.git'
```

This is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.4'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.11'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.0.rc1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.2.1'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.18.1'
end
```

Any tip how to overcome this?

Comment: Make sure you run `bundle install` and then git commit the new Gemfile.lock to  before you push to Heroku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Heroku doesn't support `SQLite`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3)

You need to keep it to your `development` group or similar:

```
#Gemfile
gem "pg", group: :production
gem "sqlite3", group: :development
```

--

As I see you have this already, you need to make sure your `Gemfile.lock` is set up correctly. The best way to do this is to run the following in your development environment:

```
$ bundle install --without production
$ bundle update
$ git add .
$ git commit -a -m "Gem"
$ git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 0):

Heroku do not support sqlite3 in  production...

You need to remove **sqlite3** from your gem file and add the following.

*From*

```
gem 'sqlite3'
```

*To*

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Important: You will have to run

git add .
git commit

before running

git push heroku master